# Why is the $t$-channel diagram for Bhabha scattering allowed?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, leptons

I thought that the individual lepton numbers $L_e$, $L_{\mu}$ and $L_{\tau}$ are individually conserved **for each vertex**.

At least this is how I explained to myself that this Feynman diagram, corresponding to the process $e^{+}e^{-} \rightarrow \mu^{+}\mu^{-}$, is not allowed:

[image]

Now I saw on Wikipedia that this Feynman diagram, however, is allowed:

[image]

But here, the lepton number is not conserved at the vertices, is it, since $L_{e} \equiv N(e^{-}) - N(e^{+}) + N(\nu_{e}) - N(\bar{\nu_e})$? So I would have said that for the upper vertex, $L_{e} = -2$, whereas for the lower vertex, $L_{e} = +2$.

Could anybody please shortly explain to me what I am missing? :-(

Comment: Lepton number conservation means the initial state lepton number must match the final state, which the second diagram does perfectly fine

Comment: So it's not conservation of lepton numbers at each vertex?

Comment: Well it's also conserved at the vertex too, but I suspect you were comparing the top to the bottom rather than left to right

Comment: Oh my, now I see, thanks a lot!!